# Somar valores com jquery, string to number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando somar alguns valores porem em vez de um resultado da soma estou obtendo os valores concatenados, segue o exemplo:

```
var a = 7.5 
var b = 1.00 
var c = 2.0
var d = a+b+c
```

`console.log(d) = 7.51.00.2.0`

Mas eu queria obter o seguinte valor:
7.5 + 1.00 + 2.0 = 10.5 para depois converter em R$ e apresentar como R$ 10,50.

Como faço para transformar esse valor concatenado no valor correto da soma?

Deveria usar `parseInt` algo do tipo `var d = parseInt(a+b+c)` mas não saiu do jeito que eu esperava.

**Update**
**Obs.:** No meu caso alguns valores estou adicionando como text() dentro da tag, em alguns casos estou pegando o data('value') da tag e adicionando o valor dentro dela via text(), tem alguma outra forma que mantem o numero como numero e não string?

Comment: use parseFloat()

Comment: Estranho!
Copiei e colei seu exemplo no jsfiddle e olha o resultado:
https://jsfiddle.net/9cvcz414/

Comment: @ISFO é que no meu caso alguns valores eu to adicionando via text() dentro da tag. Acho que pode ser isso meu problema.

Comment: @Erick use parseFloat() como falei

Comment: @RafaelAugusto to testando aqui, deu uma melhorada mas ainda não estou obtendo o valor correto do calculo, mas talvez eu tenha errado na conta, to dando uma revisada. Obrigado

Comment: Editei o codigo pegando o texto de um span

Comment: Erik viste a minha resposta? Se usares `.toFixed(2)` como sugeri, consegues transformar `10.5` em `10.50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function formatReal(int){
        var tmp = int+'';
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
        if( tmp.length > 6 )
                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

        return tmp;
}

let a = document.getElementById('a').textContent;
let b = document.getElementById('b').textContent;
let c = document.getElementById('c').textContent;

let result = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c);

$('#result').text('R$ '+formatReal(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a">10.5</span>
    <span id="b">18.9</span>
    <span id="c">45.8</span>
    
    <div id="result"></div>
```

```js
function formatReal(int){
        var tmp = int+'';
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
        if( tmp.length > 6 )
                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

        return tmp;
}

let a = document.getElementById('a').textContent;
let b = document.getElementById('b').textContent;
let c = document.getElementById('c').textContent;

let result = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c);

alert(result)
alert(formatReal(result));
```

```html
<span id="a">10.5</span>
    <span id="b">18.9</span>
    <span id="c">45.8</span>
```

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 1000;


alert(a + b);

alert(parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
```

Segue o exemplo

função `parseInt()` analisa um argumento string e retorna um inteiro na base especificada.

A função `parseFloat()` analisa um argumento string e retorna um número de ponto flutuante.

```js
let a = document.getElementById('a').textContent;
let b = document.getElementById('b').textContent;
let c = document.getElementById('c').textContent;

alert(parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c));
```

```html
<span id="a">10.5</span>
    <span id="b">18.9</span>
    <span id="c">45.8</span>
```

Comment: Como faço para pegar esse resultado e manter 2 casas decimais, pq esse valor eu vou ter que mostrar em R$.

Comment: Atualizei o codigo

Comment: @Erick adicionei no código a questão das casas decimais

Comment: To tentando adaptar no meu código aqui, acho que ta no caminho. Tinha dado certo a soma dando 10.5 agora to tentando colocar em R$ usando sua função na primeira tentativa deu `,18` rs .. mas acho que ta no caminho ... qual a melhor forma de inserir o resultado na div  to usando text();  ta certo?

Comment: Esta sim, pode usar Text sem problemas .text('R$ '+valorTotal)

Comment: Assim esta certo $(".value_per_student").text('R$ '+formatReal(y));  pq nao to conseguindo fazer o 10.5 virar 10,50 ...

Comment: @Erick atualizei o codigo

Comment: Blz seu codigo ajudou bastante nao estou conseguindo fazer meu resultado final virar 10.5 para 10,50 por exemplo ... Vou fuçar mais aqui muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Estás a usar numeros em formato *String*, precisas converter para *Number*.

Uma sugestão, usando uma função que permite *N* argumentos:

```js
var a = 6547.5;
var b = 1345354.0054;
var c = 2.0;


function somar() {
  var numeros = [].map.call(arguments, Number);
  var total = numeros.reduce(function(soma, nr) {
    return soma + nr;
  }, 0);
  return total.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
}

var d = somar(a, b, c);
console.log('R$ ' + d);
```

Comment: Como transformar ata entendi o toFixed, ele deixa com 2 casas após o .  Obrigado.

Comment: @Erick atualizei a resposta. Usando o `toLocaleString` fica mais correto.

Comment: Certo ficou legal, teria como transformar do formato dolar U$ para R$ ? 

Pq aqui no Brasil em vez de 10,000.00  usamos 10.000,00   

Obrigado

Comment: @Erick sim, essa é a ideia do `.toLocaleString` mudei na resposta para usar `'pt-BR'`